# Convert PDF to binary in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, binary

Is there any Ruby function to convert PDF to binary data.I need binary data for SOAP API. I found lot of reference for converting Binary file and some other formats , but i need the reverse.

Comment: Are you posting PDFs using soap? like trying to send a PDF file to another server using a SOAP API?

Comment: I am implementing CRM , where I need to Parse the Resume (PDF, DOC). I am using R-Chilli for parsing. They providing me SOAP Url and asking me to send file as binary data.

Comment: you can get the contents of a file like `s = File.open(filename, 'rb') { |f| f.read }` ... then send s along in your SOAP call. does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes Jesse , Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shorter to type:

```
text = IO.read(fname, mode: 'rb')
```

But SOAP isn't easy to deal with. Check out the Savon gem.

Comment: Thanks 7stud , I implemented using Savon as you suggested.